# I keep getting a "org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity" but there are no duplicates

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

For my code, I made phone as an entity object and device-specifications as an embeddable object

**Phone.java**

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity  //implement serializable?
public class Phone{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Integer id;

@Column
private String brand;

@Column
private String model;

@Column
private Specs specs;

 @Column
 private String carrier;

 @Embedded
 private Specs spec;

 public Phone() {

 }

 public Phone(String brand, String model, Specs specs, String carrier) {
     this.brand = brand;
     this.model = model;
     this.specs = specs;
     this.carrier = carrier;
 }

 public Integer getId() {
     return id;
 }

 public void setId(Integer id) {
     this.id = id;
 }

 public String getBrand() {
     return brand;
 }

 public void setBrand(String brand) {
     this.brand = brand;
 }

 public String getModel() {
     return model;
 }

 public void setModel(String model) {
     this.model = model;
 }

 public Specs getSpecs() {
     return specs;
 }

 public void setSpecs(Specs specs) {
     this.specs = specs;
 }

 public String getCarrier() {
     return carrier;
 }

 public void setCarrier(String carrier) {
     this.carrier = carrier;
 }

 public Specs getSpec() {
     return spec;
 }

 public void setSpec(Specs spec) {
     this.spec = spec;
 }
}
```

**Specs.java**

```
import javax.persistence.ElementCollection;
import javax.persistence.Embeddable;
import java.sql.Date;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;

@Embeddable
public class Specs {

private Date releaseDate;

@ElementCollection
private Map<Date, Double> priceHistory;

private Condition condition;

private double storage;

public Specs() {
}

public Specs(Date releaseDate, Map<Date, Double> priceHistory, Condition condition, double storage) {
    this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
    this.priceHistory = priceHistory;
    this.condition = condition;
    this.storage = storage;
}

public Date getReleaseDate() {
    return releaseDate;
}

public void setReleaseDate(Date releaseDate) {
    this.releaseDate = releaseDate;
}

public Map<Date, Double> getPriceHistory() {
    return priceHistory;
}

public void setPriceHistory(Map<Date, Double> priceHistory) {
    this.priceHistory = priceHistory;
}

public Condition getCondition() {
    return condition;
}

public void setCondition(Condition condition) {
    this.condition = condition;
}

public double getStorage() {
    return storage;
}

public void setStorage(double storage) {
    this.storage = storage;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Specs{" +
            "releaseDate=" + releaseDate +
            ", priceHistory=" + priceHistory.toString() +
            ", condition=" + condition +
            ", Storage=" + storage +
            '}';
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Specs specs = (Specs) o;
    return storage == specs.storage &&
            Objects.equals(releaseDate, specs.releaseDate) &&
            Objects.equals(priceHistory, specs.priceHistory) &&
            condition == specs.condition;
}

}
```

**Condition.java**

```
public enum Condition {
Refurbished("Refurbished"), Good("Good"), Fair("Fair"), Poor("Poor");
private String label;

Condition(String label) {
    this.label = label;
}

public String getLabel() {
    return label;
}

public void setLabel(String label) {
    this.label = label;
}

public static Condition findByLabel(String byLabel) {
    for(Condition r: Condition.values()) {
        if (r.label.equalsIgnoreCase(byLabel))
            return r;
    }
    return null;
}
}
```

I get this error when I run the code

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: io.zeldris.admin.adminservices.domain.Phone column: condition (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

I searched on stack overflow but the other user's issues seemed to come from table joins and mappings. However, I have not used either in my code.

Comment: The problem is using Column annotation over a complex type Specs in phone class. Do you need to map Specs relation in Phone class twice? (specs and spec). When using Embedded you don't need to redefine it with Column annotation.

Comment: @zpavel it does work thank you very much. I did not notice the double mapping.

Comment: Nice to hear it!

Answer (score 0):

Check you hbm file,your defined columns repetition.

Comment: where do I find the hbm file?